# How to regain visual access to BW6 elements?

Tags: eclipse, tibco, businessworks

I updated BW6 studio from 6.2.1 to 6.2.2 and when I reloaded a project, I ran into this issue. I'm not able to visually see the elements. I can see the elements in the outline view, which then outlines their location on the screen, as the screenshot shows.

Things I tired(and didn't work) :

- Highlighting them all, and dragging them down.
- Same as above, but using the keyboard keys and down arrowing them
- Restore from TFS, even the older versions do the same thing.

[image: Lost visual access]